# How can milvus release deleted collection in memory?

Tags: indexing, collections

1. When calling the `drop_collection()` to delete a table, why is memory not released?
2. How could milvus free up the memory space occupied by the deleted collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Because Milvus uses LRU caching strategy, memory occupied by deleted
  collection doesn't be released immediately.
- Deleted data in memory
  could be replaced by new data when the cache is full. Otherwise, you
  could try to restart Milvus to free up memory.